# Images are not visible in lollipop

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-animation, android-5.1.1-lollipop

This code works perfect on devices which are having android version other than lollipop that is below API 22

when I am trying to run this on device having API 22 (Lollipop) imgDivider2, imgIncubationCircle, imgDivider3, imgHighGrowthEnterprise these images are not visible.
I am unable to fix this bug please help...

Here is the code:-

```
public class IncubatorActivity extends Activity implements
OnClickListener, AnimatorListener 
{

Utilities util; 

ViewPager pager;

ImageView imgIsbLogo,
imgBack, 
imgMenu;

TextView txtTitle;
Intent intent;

private boolean isAnimationStart=false;
int ID, length;
String titles;

int intialRotation=360;
ImageView imgAspiringEnterprise;
ImageView imgDivider1;
ImageView imgEcoSystem, imgDivider2, imgIncubationCircle,imgDivider3, imgHighGrowthEnterprise, incubationText;

Animation zoomin;

int width;
int height;

float translateX1, translateX2, translateX3, translateX4, translateX5,
translateX6;

float translateX7, translateX8, translateX9, translateX10, translateX11, translateX12;

float translateX13, translateX14, translateX15, translateX16, translateX17, translateX18;

float translateY1, translateY2;

private int i = 0;

int animationEndCount = 0;

ImageView btNext, btPrevious;
private int value;

private boolean isNextButtonFirstTimeClick, isNextButtonSecondTimeClick, isNextButtonThirdTimeClick;

private int stepCount = 0;

private boolean isPreviousButtonFirstTimeClick, isPreviousButtonSecondTimeClick, isPreviousButtonThirdTimeClick;

private int xCount = 0;

private boolean isAnimating=false; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incubator_layout);
    util = new Utilities(IncubatorActivity.this);
    imgIsbLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.isbLogo);
    txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    imgBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backIcon);
    imgMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuIcon);
    /*imgShare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shareIcon);
    imgShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/

    txtTitle.setText("INCUBATOR");
    txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    imgIsbLogo.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgMenu.setOnClickListener(this);

    Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point mdispSize = new Point();
    mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
    width = mdispSize.x; 
    height = mdispSize.y;

    Log.d("DEVICE_WIDTH", "" + width);
    Log.d("DEVICE_HEIGHT", "" + height);

    translateX1 = (float) (-(width / 3.6));
    translateX2 = (float) (-(width / 1.1));
    //translateX3 = (float) (-(width / 0.66));
    translateX3 = (float) (-(width / 0.70));

    translateX4 = (float) (-(width / 0.72));
    translateX5 = (float) (-(width / 0.6));
    translateX6 = (float) (-(width / 0.525));

    translateX7 = (float) (-(width / 0.457));
    //translateX8 = (float) (-(width / 0.355));
    translateX8 = (float) (-(width / 0.370));
    //translateX9 = (float) (-(width / 0.2909));
    translateX9 = (float) (-(width / 0.3005));

    translateX10 = (float) (-(width / 0.2909));
    translateX11 = (float) (-(width / 0.27));
    translateX12 = (float) (-(width / 0.264));

    translateX13 = (float) (-(width / 0.246));
    translateX14 = (float) (-(width / 0.213));
    translateX15 = (float) (-(width / 0.188));

    translateX16 = (float) (-(width / 0.2));
    translateX17 = (float) (-(width / 0.183));
    translateX18 = (float) (-(width / 0.177));

    translateY1 = (float) (height/2.1);
    translateY2 = (float) (height/2.1);

    imgAspiringEnterprise = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.aspiringEnterprenuer);
    imgDivider1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.divider1);
    imgEcoSystem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ecoSystem);

    imgDivider2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.divider2);

    imgIncubationCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.incubationProcess);

    imgDivider3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.divider3);

    imgHighGrowthEnterprise = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.highGrowthEnterprises);

    incubationText = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.incubationTop);

    btNext = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bt_next);
    btPrevious = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bt_previous);
    btPrevious.setImageResource(R.drawable.previous_faded);


    if(stepCount == 0){
        btPrevious.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else{
        btPrevious.setEnabled(true);
    }

    imgEcoSystem.animate().setListener(this);
    imgHighGrowthEnterprise.animate().setListener(this);


    incubationText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    incubationText.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            long duration = 0;
            if(!isAnimationStart)
            {
                isAnimationStart=true;
                startHandler();
                //duration = imgIncubationCircle.animate().getDuration();
                imgIncubationCircle.animate().rotation(imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()-60);

                //Log.d("TouchListener", "onSwipeLeft, duration= "+duration);
            }
                        //  changeIncubationText(duration);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            long duration = 0;
            if(!isAnimationStart)
            {
                isAnimationStart=true;
                Log.d("TouchListener", "onSwipeRight");
                startHandler();
                //duration = imgIncubationCircle.animate().getDuration();
                imgIncubationCircle.animate().rotation( imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+60);
            }
                      //  changeIncubationText(duration);
        }
    });


    /*imgShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String incubator1 = IncubatorActivity.this.getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.inclubator_1);
            String incubator2 = IncubatorActivity.this.getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.inclubator_2);
            String incubator3 = IncubatorActivity.this.getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.inclubator_3);

            String textInfo = "ISB 360 \nIncubator : \n" + incubator1
                    + "\n" + incubator2 + "\n" + incubator3;

            String localImagePath = "android.resource://"
                    + IncubatorActivity.this.getPackageName() + "/"
                    + "logo_isb_to_share";
            String imageUrl = "http://digitallearning.eletsonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/logo_ISB.jpg";

            SharePopup.dispalySharePopup(
                    Utils.getCurrentView(IncubatorActivity.this),
                    IncubatorActivity.this, textInfo, imageUrl, incubator1,
                    incubator2, incubator3, localImagePath,"Share\nIncubator");

        }
    });*/
}

public void makeVisibleIncubationText(long duration){

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() { 

            incubationText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }, duration);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trial_out_from_right,
            R.anim.trial_in_from_left);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.isbLogo:

        util.HomeCall(IncubatorActivity.this, v);

        break;
    case R.id.backIcon:

        // util.BackCall(IncubatorActivity.this, v);

        onBackPressed();

        break;
    case R.id.menuIcon:
        util.MenuCall(IncubatorActivity.this, v);

        break;
    case R.id.bt_previous:
        boolean shouldDecreaseCount = false;
        System.out.println("SWAP::"+isAnimating+"::"+stepCount);
        if(!isAnimating)
            switch (stepCount) {
            case 1:
                shouldDecreaseCount = true;
                isPreviousButtonFirstTimeClick = true;

                btPrevious.setEnabled(false);
                btPrevious.setImageResource(R.drawable.previous_faded);

                btNext.setEnabled(false);
                btNext.setImageResource(R.drawable.next);

                Log.d("Previous button click", stepCount+"");
                applyAnimation(imgAspiringEnterprise, 0.2f, 0.2f, (translateX1), 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgDivider1, 0.5f, 0.5f, (translateX2), 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgEcoSystem, 0.2f, 0.2f, (translateX3), 1000);
                break;

            case 2:
                shouldDecreaseCount = true;
                isPreviousButtonSecondTimeClick = true;
                incubationText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                btPrevious.setEnabled(false);
                btNext.setEnabled(false);

                Log.d("Previous button click", stepCount+"");

                applyAnimation(imgEcoSystem, 0.2f, 0.2f, (translateX7), 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgDivider2, 0.5f, 0.5f, (translateX8), 1000);

                Log.d("Previous Button Click::Circle_Image_case2", imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+"");
                imgIncubationCircle.animate().rotation(imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+360.0f);
                imgIncubationCircle.animate().translationY(0.0f);
                applyAnimation(imgIncubationCircle, 0.2f, 0.2f, (translateX9), 1000);
                break;

            case 3:
                shouldDecreaseCount = true;
                isPreviousButtonThirdTimeClick = true;

                btPrevious.setEnabled(false);

                btNext.setEnabled(false);
                btNext.setImageResource(R.drawable.next);

                Log.d("Previous Button Click::Circle_Image_case3", imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+"");
                applyAnimation(imgIncubationCircle, 0.2f, 0.2f, (translateX13), 1000);
                makeVisibleIncubationText(2000);
                applyAnimation(imgDivider3, 0.5f, 0.5f, (translateX14), 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgHighGrowthEnterprise, 0.2f, 0.2f, (translateX15), 1000);

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }


        if(shouldDecreaseCount )
            xCount--;


        break;

    case R.id.bt_next:
        boolean shouldIncreaseCount = false;
        if (btNext.getTag() == null) {
            btNext.setTag((Integer) 0);
        }

        /* First time getTag will return 0, then 1 and so on */
        value = (Integer) btNext.getTag();
        Log.d("Button_TAG", value + "");
        System.out.println("SWAP::"+isAnimating+"::"+value);

        btPrevious.setImageResource(R.drawable.previous);
        if(!isAnimating)
            switch (value) {
            case 0:
                shouldIncreaseCount = true;
                isNextButtonFirstTimeClick = true;
                btNext.setEnabled(false);
                btPrevious.setEnabled(false);
                /* This is for first time click */
                applyAnimation(imgAspiringEnterprise, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX1, 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgDivider1, 0.5f, 0.5f, translateX2, 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgEcoSystem, 0.3f, 0.3f, translateX3, 1000);
                break;
            case 1:
                shouldIncreaseCount = true;
                isNextButtonSecondTimeClick = true;
                btNext.setEnabled(false);
                btPrevious.setEnabled(false);

                imgIncubationCircle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgDivider2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d("IMAGE_INDEX_ON_SECOND_TIME_BUTTON_CLICK", i + "");

                applyAnimation(imgEcoSystem, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX7, 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgDivider2, 0.5f, 0.5f, translateX8, 1000);

                Log.d("Next_ButtonClick::Circle_image_case1", "rotation = "+imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+"");

                applyAnimation(imgIncubationCircle, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX9, 1000);

                makeVisibleIncubationText(2000);

                break;
            case 2:
                incubationText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                shouldIncreaseCount = true;
                isNextButtonThirdTimeClick = true;
                btNext.setEnabled(false);
                btNext.setImageResource(R.drawable.next_faded);
                btPrevious.setEnabled(false);

                onStart();

                onResume();

                Log.d("IMAGE_INDEX_ON_THIRD_TIME_BUTTON_CLICK", i + "");

                Log.d("Next_Button_Click::Circle_Image_Case2", ""+imgIncubationCircle.getRotation());
                imgIncubationCircle.animate().rotation(imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+360.0f);

                imgIncubationCircle.animate().translationY(0.0f);
                applyAnimation(imgIncubationCircle, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX13, 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgDivider3, 0.5f, 0.5f, translateX14, 1000);

                applyAnimation(imgHighGrowthEnterprise, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX15, 1000);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        /* Setting number of clicked done till now as a TAG of view(value+1) */
        if(!isAnimating)
            value++;
        btNext.setTag(value);

        if(shouldIncreaseCount)
            xCount++;

        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

}



@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    isAnimating=true;
}



@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
{

    isAnimating=false;
    animationEndCount = animationEndCount + 1;

    Log.d("OnAnimationEnd", "Animation end call" + animationEndCount);
    Log.d("OnAnimationEnd", "xCount " + xCount);

    onAnimationEndFunctionalityOnNextButtonClick();
    onAnimationEndFunctionalityOnPreviousButtonClick();

    if(xCount == 1) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(treeRunnable, 200);
    } else{
        if(xCount == 2) {

        } else{

        }
        treeX = 0;
        changeTreeImage(treeX);
    }
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler();
int treeX = 0;
Runnable treeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        changeTreeImage(treeX++);
        if(treeX < 5)
            mHandler.postDelayed(treeRunnable, 1200);
    }
};



public void changeTreeImage(int x){
    int id = -1;
    switch (x) {
    case 0:
        id = R.drawable.eco_system;
        break;
    case 1:
        id = R.drawable.eco_system1;

        break;
    case 2:
        id = R.drawable.eco_system2;
        break;
    case 3:
        id = R.drawable.eco_system3;
        break;
    case 4:
        id = R.drawable.eco_system4;

        break;
    case 5:
        id = R.drawable.eco_system5;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if(id != -1)
        imgEcoSystem.setImageResource(id);
}

public void changeIncubationCircleImage(int idX){

    int id = -1;
    switch (idX) {
    case 0:
        id = R.drawable.the_incubation_process_1;
        break;
    case 1:
        id = R.drawable.the_incubation_process_2;

        break;
    case 2:
        id = R.drawable.the_incubation_process_3;
        break;
    case 3:
        id = R.drawable.the_incubation_process_4;
        break;
    case 4:
        id = R.drawable.the_incubation_process_5;

        break;
    case 5:
        id = R.drawable.the_incubation_process_6;
        break;
    case 6:
        id = R.drawable.the_incubation_process_6;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if(id != -1)
        imgIncubationCircle.setImageResource(id);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

}

private void applyAnimation(ImageView imageView, float scaleX,
        float scaleY, float translateX, long duration) {
    imageView.animate().scaleX(scaleX);
    imageView.animate().scaleY(scaleY);
    imageView.animate().translationX(translateX);
    imageView.animate().setDuration(duration);
}


private void onAnimationEndFunctionalityOnNextButtonClick()
{


    if (isNextButtonFirstTimeClick) 
    {

        applyAnimation(imgAspiringEnterprise, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX4, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgDivider1, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX5, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgEcoSystem, 1.0f, 1.0f, translateX6, 1000);

        isNextButtonFirstTimeClick = false;

        btNext.setEnabled(true);
        btPrevious.setEnabled(true);

        stepCount++;

        Log.d("Step_Count", stepCount+"");
    }

    else if (isNextButtonSecondTimeClick) 
    {

        Log.d("onAnimationEnd::isSecondTimeClick", isNextButtonSecondTimeClick + "");
        applyAnimation(imgEcoSystem, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX10, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgDivider2, 0.5f, 0.5f, translateX11, 1000);

        Log.d("OnNextButtonClick::imgIncubation rotation", ""+imgIncubationCircle.getRotation());

        imgIncubationCircle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        imgIncubationCircle.animate().rotation(imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+360.0f);

        imgIncubationCircle.animate().translationY(translateY1);
        applyAnimation(imgIncubationCircle, 2.4f, 2.4f, translateX12, 1000);

        isNextButtonSecondTimeClick = false;

        btNext.setEnabled(true);
        btPrevious.setEnabled(true);

        stepCount++;

        Log.d("Step_Count", stepCount+"");

    }

    else if (isNextButtonThirdTimeClick) 
    {


        Log.d("onAnimationEndFunctionalityOnNextButtonClick::Circle_Image "," incubation rotation = "+imgIncubationCircle.getRotation());

        int tempRotation = (int)imgIncubationCircle.getRotation();
        int mod = tempRotation % 360;

        imgIncubationCircle.animate().rotation(imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()-mod);

        applyAnimation(imgIncubationCircle, 0.2f, 0.2f, translateX16, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgDivider3, 0.5f, 0.5f, translateX17, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgHighGrowthEnterprise, 1.0f, 1.0f, translateX18, 1000);

        isNextButtonThirdTimeClick = false;

        btNext.setEnabled(false);
        btPrevious.setEnabled(true);

        stepCount++;

        Log.d("Step_Count", stepCount+"");

    }
}

private void onAnimationEndFunctionalityOnPreviousButtonClick(){

    if (isPreviousButtonFirstTimeClick) {

        Log.d("onAnimationEnd::isPreviousButtonFirstTimeClick", isPreviousButtonFirstTimeClick + "");

        applyAnimation(imgAspiringEnterprise, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgDivider1, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgEcoSystem, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1000);

        stepCount--;
        Log.d("STEP_COUNT_DECREMENT_VALUE", stepCount+"");

        btNext.setTag(stepCount);
        Log.d("NEXT_BUTTON_TAG_VALUE_AFTER_DECREMENTING_STEPCOUNT", btNext.getTag()+"");

        btNext.setEnabled(true);

        isPreviousButtonFirstTimeClick = false;
    }

    else if(isPreviousButtonSecondTimeClick){
        Log.d("onAnimationEnd::isPreviousButtonSecondTimeClick", isPreviousButtonSecondTimeClick + "");

        applyAnimation(imgEcoSystem, 1.0f, 1.0f, translateX6, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgDivider2, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1000);

        Log.d("onAnimationEnd::isPreviousButtonSecondTimeClick", imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+"");

        int tempRotation = (int)imgIncubationCircle.getRotation();
        int mod = tempRotation % 360;
        imgIncubationCircle.animate().rotation(imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()-mod);


        applyAnimation(imgIncubationCircle, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1000);

        stepCount--;
        Log.d("STEP_COUNT_DECREMENT_VALUE", stepCount+"");

        btNext.setTag(stepCount);
        Log.d("NEXT_BUTTON_TAG_VALUE_AFTER_DECREMENTING_STEPCOUNT", btNext.getTag()+"");

        btNext.setEnabled(true);
        btPrevious.setEnabled(true);

        isPreviousButtonSecondTimeClick = false;
    }

    else if (isPreviousButtonThirdTimeClick) {

        Log.d("onAnimationEnd::isPreviousButtonThirdTimeClick","rotation- "+ imgIncubationCircle.getRotation());

        imgIncubationCircle.animate().rotation(imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()+360.0f);
        imgIncubationCircle.animate().translationY(translateY2);
        applyAnimation(imgIncubationCircle, 2.5f, 2.5f, translateX12, 1000);
        applyAnimation(imgDivider3, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1000);

        applyAnimation(imgHighGrowthEnterprise, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1000);

        stepCount--;
        Log.d("STEP_COUNT_DECREMENT_VALUE", stepCount+"");

        btNext.setTag(stepCount);
        Log.d("NEXT_BUTTON_TAG_VALUE_AFTER_DECREMENTING_STEPCOUNT", btNext.getTag()+"");

        btNext.setEnabled(true);
        btPrevious.setEnabled(true);

        isPreviousButtonThirdTimeClick = false;
    }
}


/**
 * Detects left and right swipes across a view.
 */
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if(xCount != 2)
                return false;
            Log.d("onFling", "  imgIncubationCircle.getRotaion = "+imgIncubationCircle.getRotation()); 
            Log.d("onFling", "  e1.getX() = "+e1.getX());
            Log.d("onFling", "  e2.getX() = "+e2.getX());
            float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0)
                    onSwipeRight();
                else
                    onSwipeLeft();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
private Handler handler=new Handler();

private void startHandler()
{
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isAnimationStart=false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
}
```

And the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    layout="@layout/action_bar_for_sub" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutImages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aspiringEnterprenuer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/aspiringEnterpreneur_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/aspiring_entrepreneur"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/divider1_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/divider1_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/divider"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ecoSystem"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ecosystem_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ecosystem_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/eco_system"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/divider2_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/divider2_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/divider"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/incubationProcess"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/incubator_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/incubator_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/the_incubation_process_0"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/divider3_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/divider3_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/divider"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/highGrowthEnterprises"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/highgrowth_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/highgrowth_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/high_growth_enterprises"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/incubationTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/the_incubation_text"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bt_previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/previous"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bt_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/next"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the dimensions

```
<dimen name="aspiringEnterpreneur_width">330dp</dimen>
<dimen name="aspiringEnterpreneur_height">297dp</dimen>
<dimen name="divider1_width">355dp</dimen>
<dimen name="divider1_height">297dp</dimen>
<dimen name="ecosystem_width">297dp</dimen>
<dimen name="ecosystem_height">297dp</dimen>
<dimen name="divider2_width">370dp</dimen>
<dimen name="divider2_height">297dp</dimen>
<dimen name="incubator_width">320dp</dimen>
<dimen name="incubator_height">297dp</dimen>
<dimen name="divider3_width">350dp</dimen>
<dimen name="divider3_height">297dp</dimen>
<dimen name="highgrowth_width">325dp</dimen>
<dimen name="highgrowth_height">297dp</dimen>
<dimen name="appli_pro_stap1_btn_stage_width">86dp</dimen> 
<dimen name="appli_pro_stap1_btn_stage_height">38dp</dimen>
```

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the images, in pre-lollipop devices?

Comment: 1]http://i.stack.imgur.com/6S1fM.png
2]http://i.stack.imgur.com/8f5Yp.png 
3]http://i.stack.imgur.com/j7GNm.png
These are the images I am using.

Comment: Ok.. the reason i asked the images was, my guess is that, from Lollipop, we need to specify the color for each of the view, for example, if you have a textview and you haven't set the color to it, it will just appear fine in pre-lollipop devices, where as from lollipop, they just become invisible(esp if the background of the screen is white). So if possible, try changing the background color of the top RelativeLayout, to some solid color and check if the images appear. Not sure if that works.. but.. worth a try

Comment: I know, the images are not white to blend in the background.. but, just one more test.

Comment: I am using an image as a background for the top relative layout...
    
    android:background="@drawable/bg"

Comment: one more thing that i have noticed is on lollipop, if I turn off the screen of the device and then again turn it on, then the images are visible.